# Simple OS: undefined referance to kmain

Tags: c++, assembly

Hi i am writing a simple Os in assembly and c++ I finished writing my .asm file I am rwally new to assembly so I just copy pasted and tried to understand the code but...

```
    BITS 16


%INCLUDE "print.asm"
extern _kmain

start:
    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax








    call _kmain

    jmp $           ; Jump here - infinite loop!








    times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
    dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

and i have a c++ file

```
void kmain(void)
{
    const char *str = "hello";
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;  //video mem begins here.
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 0;

    /* this loops clears the screen
    * there are 25 lines each of 80 columns; each element takes 2 bytes */
    while(j < 80 * 25 * 2) {
        /* blank character */
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
        /* attribute-byte - light grey on black screen */
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x07;         
        j = j + 2;
    }

    j = 0;

    /* this loop writes the string to video memory */
    while(str[j] != '\0') {
        /* the character's ascii */
        vidptr[i] = str[j];
        /* attribute-byte: give character black bg and light grey fg */
        vidptr[i+1] = 0x07;
        ++j;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    return;
}
```

I made .o files from thembut When I use

```
ld -m i386pe -O OS.tmp a.o as.o
```

it gives error:::

:Bootloader.asm: undefined reference to `kmain'

Comment: Problem is c++ does name mangling. Try `extern "C" void kmain(void)` instead of `void kmain(void)`

Comment: It might be complex to use C++ (not only name mangling, but also exception handling, ...) in a kernel. See http://osdev.org/

Comment: An observation though. GCC/G++ generated code doesn't play nice in real mode unless you know what you are doing and even then it has pitfalls and limitations (ES=DS=CS=SS=0 gives the least hassles and you'll need to be in **unreal mode**). Not sure how you are compiling and whether you are using `-m16` option when compiling. As it stands you are probably going to encounter issues with this. Your bootloader should really put the processor into 32-bit protected mode. You might want to consider a multiboot compliant bootloader like GRUB and create a multibot header and entry point.